# cvxopt : solver.cp gives a wrong awnser

Tags: python, convex-optimization, cvxopt

I am trying to solve a simple convex optimisation problem with cvxopt. I want to maximize the ROI function with x and y >=1 and x+y<=6

```py
import numpy as np
def ROI(x,y):
    return np.exp(-x)*x*10+np.exp(-y)*y**2*10
```

then I use cvxopt to minimize -ROI(x,y) subject to  G*(x,y)' <= h

```py
from cvxopt import solvers, blas, matrix, spmatrix, spdiag, log, div
G=matrix([[-1.,0.,1.],[0.,-1.,1.]],(3,2))
h=matrix([-4.,-1.,6.],(3,1))
def F(x=None, z=None):
    if(x is None):
        return 0,matrix([1.,1.],(2,1))
    f = - ROI(x[0],x[1])
    grad = matrix([(10*x[0]-10)*np.exp(-x[0]),(10*x[1]**2-20*x[1])*np.exp(-x[1])]) 
    if (z is None):
        return f,grad.T
    d = [(-10*x[0]+20)*np.exp(-x[0])*z[0],(-10*x[1]**2-20+40*x[1])*np.exp(-x[1])*z[0]] 
    H = spdiag(d) 
    return f, grad.T, H
sol = solvers.cp(F, G, h)
```

the optimal solution given by the solver is (5,1) which is false, for example ROI(4,2)>ROI(5,1). Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has answered their question by saying their question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry my question does not make any sence since the function ROI is not concave...